# function that input an integer and return a function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

Totally get lost of the following example that returning a function

```
getAddFunc :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
getAddFunc x y = x + y
adds3 = getAddFunc 3
fourPlus3 = adds3 4
```

the function signature `Int -> (Int -> Int)` told me it accept an `Int` and function that typed `Int -> Int` And I am very confused about the function definition `x y = x + y`, it looks like it took 2 integers x and y rather than just 1 integer! What's the meaning of x and y here? I am very confused.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: does it make more sense after reading [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions)?

Comment: It's the beauty of haskell

Comment: @ShamPooSham just start that beauty journey for 40 min :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All functions in Haskell take *one* parameter. Indeed, the function:

```
getAddFunc x y = x + y
```

is equivalent to:

```
getAddFunc x = \y -> x + y
```

and to:

```
getAddFunc = \x -> \y -> x + y
```

You thus construct a function that takes a parameter `x`, and it maps it to a function that takes a parameter `y` and will return `x + y`.

This thus means that `getAddFunc 42` is a function that takes a parameter and will add 42 to it.

The `(->)` type constructor is *right associative*. Indeed, `Int -> (Int -> Int)` is the same as `Int -> Int -> Int`.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at a curried function. The code

```
getAddFunc x y = x + y
```

is equivalent to

```
getAddFunc x = \y -> x + y
```

i.e., taking `x` as argument and returning a function of `y`.

This can also be written

```
getAddFunc = \x -> \y -> x + y
```

or

```
getAddFunc = \x y -> x + y
```

In Haskell, from a technical point of view, every function takes exactly *one* argument. However, after taking that argument, it can return another function taking as input a "second" argument. This mechanism can also be interpreted as a function taking "two" arguments. This further generalizes to N arguments in a similar way.